# SQL Server Extended Property MS_SubdatasheetName

Tags: sql, sql-server, extended-properties

Our application uses a SQL Server back-end with many stored procedures.  Recently, while trying to fix an unrelated problem, we scripted a stored procedure to an ALTER statement to a SQL window to try something.  Renaming our proc for testing purposes, we ran the script, and got this perplexing error:

```
Msg 15233, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_addextendedproperty, Line 37
    Property cannot be added. 
    Property 'MS_SubdatasheetName' already exists for 'dbo.sp_One_Of_Our_Stored_Procedures'.
```

The ALTER statement had included code to set an extended property:

```
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_SubdatasheetName', @value=N'[None]' , 
    @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', 
    @level1type=N'PROCEDURE',@level1name=N'sp_One_Of_Our_Stored_Procedures'
```

Our code does not create or reference this property anywhere.  We're puzzled by where it came from.

Does anyone know which software creates and uses this extended property and what the setting would mean?  A Google search didn't help.  From the search results, I would guess the property has something to do with Microsoft Access, but what does it mean?

Comment: Here is something that may shed light on what you're searching for http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/thread-3832564.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does come from MS Access.

*KB275085 explains that the extended property MS_SubdataSheetName setting
effects whether the SYSREFENCES or INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
is cached on the first open of a SQL VIEW or TABLE for an ADP. The article
says it applies to MDBs only, but it also applies to ADPs.*

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/275085

Also, since the property is already created, you can work around it by using `sp_UpdateExtendedProperty`